# Removing objects from a layer using KineticJS

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I am currently working a project involving KineticJS.

I have to dynamically create and delete shapes constantly, but cannot seem to figure out how to do the latter. I've been trying to do:

```
 $ myLayer.remove(myShape)
```

because this is what most posts seem to recommend. But, the documentation says that this will remove the layer from the stage and not the shape from the layer. When I try this in project it in fact removes the layer from the stage.

So am I doing something wrong or is there some other way to remove a shape from a layer?

Comment: I don't know if there is a better way, but after reading some of the kinetic js code. I found if I do myShape.remove() the shape gets removed from the layer.

Answer (score 17):

There are two functions that may be helpful.

- `childContainer.remove()` removes the childContainer from it's parent.
- `parentContainer.removeChildren()` removes all the children from this container.

**Edit**: This can also apply to shapes. Simply redraw the layer.

```
myShape.remove();
myLayer.draw();
```

Comment: thanx, i just wanted to know this! found out that you don´t even need to redraw the layer, after calling remove it´s gone immediately.

Comment: How to restore it again??

Comment: @MahdiAlkhatib if you still have a reference to the children then simply add them to the layer / container

Comment: So if there are no variable pointing to it, it will be destroyed (garbage collected)??

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere between Kinetic 4.0 and the latest version, remove(child) stopped working. removeChild(child) doesn't work either.

I resolved this problem by using child.remove();

Answer (score 0):

U can use the prototype of kinetic function

`Kinetic.Node.prototype.remove.call(removed_object);`

`baselayer.draw();`