# draw multiple lines and delete individual line

Tags: draw, kineticjs

I can draw multiple lines on the canvas; they are added to the layer using drawScene

```
dlayerA1.add(line);
line.getPoints()[0].x = mousePos.x;
line.getPoints()[0].y = mousePos.y;
line.getPoints()[1].x = mousePos.x;
line.getPoints()[1].y = mousePos.y;
moving = true;
dlayerA1.drawScene();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/user373721/xzEad/1/.

Is there a way to delete individual line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assigned a unique id to each object and used the following to delet it when click on it:

```
                         r = r + 1;
                        var mousePos = stage1.getMousePosition();
                        rectA1 = new Kinetic.Rect({
                            x: mousePos.x - rOffset,
                            y: mousePos.y - rOffset,
                            width: 0,
                            height: 0,
                            stroke: 'red',
                            strokeWidth: 4,
                            id:"rectA" + r
                          });

                        rectA1.setListening(true);
                         myRect1[r] = rectA1;
                        background1.add(myRect1[r]);
                        //start point and end point are the same
                        rectA1.setX(mousePos.x - rOffset);
                        rectA1.setY(mousePos.y - rOffset);
                        rectA1.setWidth(0);
                        rectA1.setHeight(0);
                        moving = true;

                        background1.drawScene();
                        myRect1[r].on("click", function () {  

                            this.remove();
                        });
```

My solution is based on this good answer: [How to select an object in kinetic.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315925/how-to-select-an-object-in-kinetic-js)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you'll have to modify the points array like this:

line.getPoints()[0].splice(index, 1);

Since arrays are modified by reference, modifying the returned array modifies the "source of truth" points array attr

Comment: Thanks Eric, is there an example somewhere I check out.